Getting "invalid-input-response" from Google reCAPTCHA v3 in .NET Web API with Angular frontend
I'm working on integrating Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my .NET backend and Angular frontend. I’ve set up the backend to verify the reCAPTCHA token with Google’s reCAPTCHA API, but I'm getting a response with "success": false and "error-codes": ["invalid-input-response"].
Here’s my setup:
.NET Backend (ASP.NET Core)
The backend method captchaTokenVerify sends the token and secret key to Google’s verification endpoint:
public async Task<DataTable> captchaTokenVerify(string secret, string siteToken)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Success", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(decimal));
    dt.Columns.Add("ErrorMessage", typeof(string));

    try
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "secret", secret },
            { "response", siteToken }
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json = JObject.Parse(responseString);

        bool success = json["success"].Value<bool>();
        decimal score = json.ContainsKey("score") ? json["score"].Value<decimal>() : 0;
        string errorMessage = success ? null : json["error-codes"]?.ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(success, score, errorMessage);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(false, 0, $"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return dt;
    }
}

Angular Frontend
In my Angular service, I call the .NET endpoint to verify the reCAPTCHA token, passing in the token received from Google:
// Angular service
captchaTokenVerify(token: string) {
    console.log('tok', token);
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.getBaseUrl()}Auth/captchaTokenVerify?secret=${environment.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_V3}&siteToken=${token}`);
}

// Triggering reCAPTCHA verification
public executeRecaptchaV3() {
    this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(environment.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_V3, 'myAction', (token) => {
        this.authService.captchaTokenVerify(token).subscribe({
            next: (res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
            },
            error: (err) => {
                this.notification.showError('Oops!', validateForm.getErrorMessage(err));
            },
        });
    });
}

Here’s a question you could post on Stack Overflow to get feedback on the issue with the invalid-input-response error:
Title:
Getting "invalid-input-response" from Google reCAPTCHA v3 in .NET Web API with Angular frontend
Body:
I'm working on integrating Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my .NET backend and Angular frontend. I’ve set up the backend to verify the reCAPTCHA token with Google’s reCAPTCHA API, but I'm getting a response with "success": false and "error-codes": ["invalid-input-response"].
Here’s my setup:
.NET Backend (ASP.NET Core)
The backend method captchaTokenVerify sends the token and secret key to Google’s verification endpoint:
public async Task<DataTable> captchaTokenVerify(string secret, string siteToken)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Success", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("Score", typeof(decimal));
    dt.Columns.Add("ErrorMessage", typeof(string));

    try
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "secret", secret },
            { "response", siteToken }
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json = JObject.Parse(responseString);

        bool success = json["success"].Value<bool>();
        decimal score = json.ContainsKey("score") ? json["score"].Value<decimal>() : 0;
        string errorMessage = success ? null : json["error-codes"]?.ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(success, score, errorMessage);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(false, 0, $"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return dt;
    }
}

Angular Frontend
In my Angular service, I call the .NET endpoint to verify the reCAPTCHA token, passing in the token received from Google:
// Angular service
captchaTokenVerify(token: string) {
    console.log('tok', token);
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.getBaseUrl()}Auth/captchaTokenVerify?secret=${environment.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_V3}&siteToken=${token}`);
}

// Triggering reCAPTCHA verification
public executeRecaptchaV3() {
    this.recaptchaV3Service.execute(environment.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY_V3, 'myAction', (token) => {
        this.authService.captchaTokenVerify(token).subscribe({
            next: (res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
            },
            error: (err) => {
                this.notification.showError('Oops!', validateForm.getErrorMessage(err));
            },
        });
    });
}

Issue
The response from the Google reCAPTCHA API is:
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": ["invalid-input-response"]
}

What I’ve Tried
Checked the token: Verified that the token is generated by recaptchaV3Service.execute on the frontend.
Used FormUrlEncodedContent: Ensured the data is encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the .NET backend.
Verified secret key: Confirmed that I'm using the correct secret key from my Google reCAPTCHA admin console.
Questions
1.) What could be causing the invalid-input-response error here?
2.) Is there anything I’m missing in the backend or frontend setup that might be leading to this error?

Have you found a solution?

@SamAlekseev no i haven't, still waiting
